# How could i define anonymous type?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0, anonymous-types

I have anonymous type variable which i am populating like that(i have two variables `jsonDataCache` and `jsonData` but i want to have just one, `jsonData` for example) :

```
 var jsonData = new
            {
                total = totalPages,
                page = page,
                records = totalRecords,

                rows = (from b in myData
                select new
                        {
                        //do things
                        }).ToArray()
             };
return Json(jsonData, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

But if i want to define this variable first, before i do populate that, basically i want to do something like that:

```
var jsonData = null;   

//check if jsonData in cache and if it is return Json(jsonData, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

jsonData = new
                {
                    total = totalPages,
                    page = page,
                    records = totalRecords,

                    rows = (from b in myData
                    select new
                            {
                            //do things
                            }).ToArray()
                 };
//put jsonData in cache by key

return Json(jsonData, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

How could i do that?

The reason i want to do that because i want to introduce the cache, so i need to define the variable first ant than check that in cache and if it is not i will do the thing above.
Currently i did that with two variables, bot i want to use just one.

Here is how i currently done that:

```
public virtual JsonResult GetSomething(int id, int type)
{
   string keyPrefix = GetKeyPrefix(id, type);

   var jsonDataCache = CacheManager.Get<object>(keyPrefix);   

    if(jsonDataCache != null)
      return Json(jsonDataCache, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

    var myData = GetFromDataase();

    var jsonData = new
                    {
                        total = totalPages,
                        page = page,
                        records = totalRecords,

                        rows = (from b in myData
                        select new
                                {
                                //do things
                                }).ToArray()
                     };

    CacheManager.Set<object>(keyPrefix, jsonData);

    return Json(jsonData, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

**UPDATE:**
After all your help I think it should be something like that, hopefully it is right way to go:

```
public virtual JsonResult GetSomething(int id, int type)
{
   string keyPrefix = GetKeyPrefix(id, type);

   var jsonData = CacheManager.Get<object>(keyPrefix);   

    if(jsonData != null)
      return Json(jsonData , JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

    var myData = GetFromDataase();

    jsonData = new
                    {
                        total = totalPages,
                        page = page,
                        records = totalRecords,

                        rows = (from b in myData
                        select new
                                {
                                //do things
                                }).ToArray()
                     };

    CacheManager.Set<object>(keyPrefix, jsonData);

    return Json(jsonData, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Comment: *why* do you want to do that? This question is probably key to finding an appropriate answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do that (and initialize to null), except for some really nasty and ugly "by example" tactics with generic methods. Variables to anonymous types can only be declared alongside initialisation (except as a generic type parameter).

It does, however, seem unlikely that you really need it here. Indeed,

```
object jsonData;
```

would suffice, since you never *use* the value. Beyond that, I'd argue that it is time to introduce a DTO class for the purpose instead.

Answer (score 3):

Well, you can create it "by example" - with the same property names and types, in the same order, just with dummy values. For example:

```
var jsonData = new { total = 0, page = 0, records = 0,
                     rows = new[] { new { dummy = "" } };
```

It wasn't clear what you wanted the nested anonymous type to do, so I just created one with a string property called `dummy`.

Note that I'd *try* to avoid doing this sort of thing normally... as Marc says, if you can explain the bigger picture, it will help us to help you more.

EDIT: If it's for caching, how were you expecting to create the declare the cache in a statically-typed way? What is your Json method declared to accept? If it's declared to accept `object`, you don't *need* a strongly-typed variable, do you? If it's generic, that's fine - but it'll come back to how you manage to cast whatever's coming out of the cache appropriately...

Comment: question updated, may be better to go with object like @Jamie Dixon suggested?

Comment: @jason: I've updated my answer - but your question still isn't really clear... as if you're not *really* clear in your own mind about how this is meant to work. What is the signature of the Json method, for example? How would you expect to declare the cache?

Comment: @jason: So in the working code, the `jsonDataCache` variable is of type `object` - why can't you use that elsewhere, as per Marc's answer?

Comment: looks like I get it. I just was a bit confused with anonymous types.

Comment: I hope it is right thing to store `anonymous object` in cache as `object` type

Comment: @jason: Yes, that's fine - but you won't be able to get it *out* of the cache in a strongly-typed way.

Answer (score 1):

It's unclear why you'd want to do this but here's one way:

You can create your object as type `object` or `dynamic`

```
object foo = null;

foo = new {
 bar = "bar"
};
```

**Update:**

Given your update I think there's a much more appropriate way to do this.

Personally I use the `System.Web.Caching.Cache` and have an extension method which checks the cache for your item (based on the cache key) or executes your method to retrieve the data.

```
public static T GetOrStore<T>(this Cache cache, string key, Func<T> generator)
        {
            var result = cache.Get(key);
            if(result == null)
            {
                result = generator();
                cache.Insert(key,result);
            }

            return (T) result;
        }
```

Which you can use like:

```
var jsonData = Cache.GetOrStore("jsonData", Foo);
```

where:

```
private static string Foo()
{
   return new {[...]}
}
```

Comment: i was thinking to do that bat wasn't sure that it is would work

Comment: Well you'll be able to perform the assignment - but you won't be able to use it in a strongly typed way.

Comment: @jason See my update. I think this is more like what you want.