# Combine two anonymous types

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0, anonymous-types

I asked the related question before and get gretat ansfer on that [How could i define anonymous type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7370984/how-could-i-define-anonymous-type)

But now i am wondering is it possible to combine two anonymous types

Basically i am storing some weekly data in cache like i described in related queston

So in case i have `anonymous type` stored as `object` it is contain some data for current week
and i want to append today's data to that object everyday.

So i have data in `anonymous type` as `object` from one side and from another i have completely the same structured  `anonymous type` and i want do append/add data from my new `anonymous type` to the old one which is `anonymous type` as `object` and put it back to cache.

If you would look my related question my anonymous type looking like that:

```
var jsonData = new { total = 0, page = 0, records = 0,
                     rows = new[] { new { dummy = "" } };
```

So the question is how could i combine anonymous types in my case?

For example if it would be two collections i would go like that

```
List<Data> weeklyFromCahce = GetFromCache()
List<Data> todaysToCahce = GetFromDataBase();
```

and than i would loop though `todaysToCahce` and add each item to `weeklyFromCahce` and that put updated `weeklyFromCahce` back to cache.

So i want to do similar process but with anonymous types in my case. The combined result should be the `anonymous type` which would contain weekly data + current day data and that i update cache with the new `anonymous type` which would contain combined result of two anonymous instances.

Comment: "Combine" how exactly? Give us two instances and an example of what the combined result should be.

Comment: Why would you insist on anonymous types? If the same data format is used in more than one place, you can introduce an object.

Comment: @henginy probably it is the way to go

Answer (score 1):

```
var x = new { member1 = 123 };
var y = new { member2 = "qwerty" };
var z = new { part1 = x, part2 = y }; // combined
```

?

**Updated after TS comment**

```
var x = new { member1 = 123 };
var y = new { member2 = "qwerty" };
var z = new { member1 = x.member1, member2 = y.member2 }; // combined
```

**Update 2**

```
class DynamicPair<TX, TY> : DynamicObject
{
    private readonly TX _x;
    private readonly TY _y;

    public DynamicPair(TX x, TY y)
    {
        _x = x;
        _y = y;
    }

    public override bool TryGetMember(GetMemberBinder binder, out object result)
    {
        try
        {
            var property = typeof (TX).GetProperty(binder.Name);
            if (property != null)
            {
                result = property.GetValue(_x, null);
                return true;
            }

            property = typeof (TY).GetProperty(binder.Name);
            if (property != null)
            {
                result = property.GetValue(_y, null);
                return true;
            }
        }
        catch
        {
        }

        result = null;
        return false;
    }

    public override bool TrySetMember(SetMemberBinder binder, object value)
    {
        // too lazy
        return true;
    }
}


class Program
{
    private static DynamicPair<TX, TY> Combine<TX, TY>(TX x, TY y)
    {
        return new DynamicPair<TX, TY>(x, y);
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var x = new { a = 123 };
        var y = new { b = 222 };
        dynamic z = Combine(x, y);
        Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}", z.a, z.b);
    }
}
```

Not exactly sure if it's acceptable in your case, but still it works.

Comment: no not really combined :) the result is `anonymous type` which contains two separate `anonymous objects`, not `one` like i want.